# usage of BUNDLEGEMFILE in Rubygems system

Tags: ruby, bundle

I find a command about BUNDLEGEMFILE in Rubygems system, which looks like that:

```
BUNDLEGEMFILE=Gemfile bundle exec bosh target 192.168.50.4
```

`bosh` is a command line interface, bosh_cli.

And, the `Gemfile` of the project is shown below:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'librarian-chef'
gem 'bosh_cli'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rake'
  gem 'rspec'
end
```

Usually, I exec the command above like: `bosh target 192.168.50.4`, however, I find the command `BUNDLEGEMFILE=Gemfile bundle exec bosh target 192.168.50.4` also works.
So, I wonder the meanings of `BUNDLEGEMFILE=Gemfile` and `bundle exec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bundler](http://bundler.io/) is a dependency management tool. It uses the `Gemfile` to configure application specific dependencies. `bundle exec` takes care of setting up the path to include the dependencies in the `Gemfile` and execute the given command within that context. `BUNDLEGEMFILE` is an environment variable that you can use when you want to tell bundler that the `Gemfile` is something other than `Gemfile`. This is usually used when having multiple Gemfiles or some strange location of that file.